# Unable to process system update with apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, networking, updates

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to install a package or update.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-60-64:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports /InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've seen other answers relating to this problem. But, none of them worked. The instance is running in AWS and the traffic rules are properly set.

Ifconfig output as follows..

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:d2:b3:9a:b4:c8
      inet addr:172.31.60.64  Bcast:172.31.63.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::10d2:b3ff:fe9a:b4c8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
      RX packets:3436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:277901 (277.9 KB)  TX bytes:307892 (307.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The nslookup is...

```
nslookup archive.ubuntu.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This question has been marked as duplicate. But, the original question did not resolve my issue.

Contents of /etc/hosts

```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   127.0.1.1 ip-172-31-60-64

   # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0 ip6-localnet
   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
   ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: Can you ping archive.ubuntu.com and  security.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: Ping returns Unknown Host.

Comment: Then you have some problem in your network config. Please update the question with the output from `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com` and `ifconfig`

Comment: Did you see the "In AWS, go to your vpc and turn on "DNS Hostnames" in the proposed answer ?

Comment: Can you append the contents of the file `/etc/hosts` to your question, please?

Comment: That was not a problem. @SorenA